# How to determine whether web traffic has gone up or down over a 12 month period?

Tags: regression, time-series, trend

I have traffic data for a website that simply shows total visitor each month over 12 months. I'm trying to establish if there's a general trend upwards or downwards.

I seem to remember from high school maths that it would be whether or not there's a positive $m$ value in the equation $y = mx + c$ but I have no idea on how to apply this practically, and given a bunch of dates and totals, work this figure out.

**How to determine whether web traffic has gone up or down over a 12 month period?**

Comment: If you're just looking for upward trend that can occur without the relationship being linear.

Comment: Further, with time series, there's the strong possibility of time-dependence (autocorrelation) along with the trend. Simply fitting a straight line (say by least squares) may be unsuitable. Note also that your data are counts, and so are unlikely to have constant variance, for example.

Comment: If you had neither autocorrelation nor seasonality, a Mann-Kendall trend test might be suitable.

Comment: Thanks Glen. I appreciate seasonality can have an influence, and didn't necessarily think that through. I'll investigate the Mann-Kendall trend.

Comment: For this purpose, the simplest solution might just be to look at a plot of the data in Excel with a superimposed [trendline](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-change-or-remove-a-trendline-in-a-chart-HP010007461.aspx). Not necessarily statistically rigorous, but I think this would allow an at-a-glance assessment of whether traffic is rising or falling.

Comment: @DJE There are even simpler yet rigorous solutions, such as comparing the mean of the more recent values to the mean of the earliest values. This overcomes (a) possible problems with autocorrelation (by leaving a suitable temporal gap between the early and recent values) and (b) problems with assuming linearity (because no such assumption is needed, although implicitly we assume there is no *appreciable* trend during the "early" and "recent" time periods). These solutions can be implemented with a t-test or Wilcoxon test (albeit preferably after a suitable re-expression of the data).

Comment: (Continued) This simple approach also handles possible annual seasonality because it compares (at least to a good approximation) year-over-year data. Its principal disadvantage is the paucity of information: with just 12 monthly results, there is a clear tradeoff between the power achieved by making stronger assumptions (such as linear change over time) against the lack of power, in the absence of such assumptions, due to the small amount of data. You have to pick your poison. But perhaps traffic data might be available on a weekly or even daily basis... .

Comment: DJE - this is something which will be automated and done via a script, so plotting the data on Excel isn't an option. What I'm ideally looking for is a similar to what @whuber suggested where I can setup a formula in PHP and store the output.

Comment: @whuber - thanks. This seems like the best idea.